# Error: Transaction's maxFeePerGas (0) is less than the block's baseFeePerGas (527514873)

Tags: web3.py, gas-price, gas-limit, brownie, ganache-cli

Not Able to deploy to Ganache- Local chain,
I have tried using func from Web3.eth , tried to import GasNowStrategy, Redownload the ganache as well and also tried to copy exact same code from GIT. Still facing same error
This is exact error:

ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'Error: Transaction's maxFeePerGas (0) is less than the block's baseFeePerGas (527514873) (vm hf=arrowGlacier -> block number=5 hash=0x970ba9015a3e3d50702d030dbda68f954af105f1f7151a86cbb9e1689e276593 hf=arrowGlacier baseFeePerGas=527514873 txs=0 uncles=0 -> tx type=0 hash=0x9d11dbd492c7ba143584b7928637c44e654540e48e513cfdb457230a93334544 nonce=4 value=0 signed=true hf=arrowGlacier gasPrice=0)'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This happens due to [EIP-1559](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1559), which was added with the London block.

The protocol thus calculates a `baseFeePerGas`, which is the minimum price every transaction has to pay per unit of gas.
On top of that, the EIP-1559 provides two extra parameters, which a user can include in the transaction. Those namely are:

- `maxPriorityFeePerGas`. A tip to the miner to incentivize addition of the transaction to the next block.
- `maxFeePerGas`. A maximum price that a transactor is willing to pay for the unit of gas.

Thus during the transaction construction process, the condition `baseFeePerGas + maxPriorityFeePerGas =< maxFeePerGas` has to be satisfied.

However, in your case the above condition does not hold because `baseFeePerGas = 527514873` and `maxFeePerGas = 0`, as stated by the error:

> ...maxFeePerGas (0) is less than the block's baseFeePerGas (527514873)...

To solve this issue, please consider passing an additional `maxFeePerGas` parameter to your transaction object, which would at least be equal to the `baseFeePerGas`.

**Note:**
Make sure that your account balance is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The Ethereum [London fork](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/#base-fee) introduced a block-level base fee. Your transaction must set a gas price equal to or higher than the next block's base fee.

From python web3, you can use [Eth.fee_history](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.fee_history) to get the base fee.

You can also get the base fee from latest block:

```py
block = web3.eth.get_block('latest')
next_gas_price = math.ceil(block.get('baseFeePerGas') * 1.251)
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on GitHub20292's answer. You need to add `maxFeePerGas` (JS) or `max_fee_per_gas` (Python) whenever you're sending or signing a transaction.

Example (for `Web.js`)

```
const block = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
const next_gas_price = Math.ceil(block.baseFeePerGas);
const signRes = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
  to: recieverData.address,
  value: web3.utils.toWei(amountToSend.toString(), 'ether'),
  maxFeePerGas: next_gas_price,
  gas: 100000,
}, sendersData.privateKey);
```